# How to print c_ubyte_Array object in Python

Tags: python, c, printing, ctypes

What is the best way to print the contents of a C unsigned char array in Python,

if I use `print theStruct.TheProperty`

I get...

`<structs.c_ubyte_Array_8 object at 0x80fdb6c>`

The definition is:

`class theStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("TheProperty", c_ubyte * 8)]`

Desired output something like:
`Mr Smith`

Comment: The best way to print any object is the one that gives the desired output. Nothing more than this can be said until you do not specify what your desired output is.

Comment: I came here looking how to print elements of a ctypes structure.  Short form: in python3, wrap it in a bytes() constructor and you can treat it like any Python array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's a null-terminated string, you can cast the array to a `char *` and use its `value`. Here's an example where that's not the case.

```
>>> class Person(Structure): _fields_ = [("name", c_ubyte * 8), ('age', c_ubyte)]
... 
>>> smith = Person((c_ubyte * 8)(*bytearray('Mr Smith')), 9)
>>> smith.age
9
>>> cast(smith.name, c_char_p).value
'Mr Smith\t'
```

"Mr Smith" fills up the array, so casting to `c_char_p` includes the value of the next field, which is 9 (ASCII tab), and who knows what else, however much until it reaches a null byte.

Instead you can iterate the array with `join`:

```
>>> ''.join(map(chr, smith.name))
'Mr Smith'
```

Or use a bytearray:

```
>>> bytearray(smith.name)
bytearray(b'Mr Smith')
```

Python 3:

```
>>> smith = Person((c_ubyte * 8)(*b'Mr Smith'), 9)
>>> bytes(smith.name).decode('ascii')
'Mr Smith'
```